# What would be the lifestyle of a type omega alien civilization?

Tags: aliens, civilization

I'm designing a planet that has reached the top level of civilization.

This species has left behind the need for violence, they have found a way to live in peace with their planet's ecosystem and they have interstellar travel that allows them to visit other universes.

Their economic system is based on knowledge (if someone wants to buy something he or she has to learn something new, the more you learn the more you can buy), they can build massive megastructures and they can terraform another planet within a few hours.

They have achieved immortality and therefore everyone is at the same age (they grow until some point and then stop), they have utopian like cities, there is no poverty there (neither racism or sexism), they have found a way to prevent stars from dying, they think that competition is something pointless and they have found a way to create their own universes or pocket dimensions.

But back to the question: What could their lifestyle be like on their home-world? What could their everyday life be like for them?

Note: I know that people say that a type omega civilization would probably live outside the space-time continuum, but I decided to say that they still live on their home-world.

Comment: Try to avoid the wall of the text, use shorter periods and line breaks.

Comment: The justification for a Vote To Close reason of Primarily Opinion Based id "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."  What facts, references, or specific expertise would allow people to form fact-based answers?

Comment: @RonJohn, [the SE definition of POB doesn't work here, otherwise no question about magic could be answered](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).

Comment: John, this Q was IMO inappropriately closed as POB, but it's too story based.  You've created godlike beings in a utopia no one can relate to.  What would be their lifestyle?  Beats me.  What do godlike beings who have no sense of competition do?  Said another way, the lifestyle is basically anything you want it to be and is very much dependent on the story.  Also, just to make a point, learing something new to gain trade value in a society that thinks competiton is pointless only lasts until the first guy wants the last piece of pie.  Then competition begins in earnest.

Comment: @JBH there is no magic tag, and even if you call it TSB instead of POB, you yourself wrote, "*the lifestyle is basically anything you want it to be*".

Comment: @RonJohn, complaining that there isn't a magic tag is petulant.  The POB perspective you're hanging on to doesn't exist on this site.

Comment: @JBH I'm not the only person to disagree with you about this.

Comment: @RonJohn, then take it up in Meta.  No rule can or should exist that cannot be consistently applied to all questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***All I Know is that I wouldn’t want to live their***

The human race has many, many flaws. Way more than I can right in a single answer. But the flaws are what give life meaning. I may be miserable sometimes, but the misery is what gives the joy weight. Having everything handed to you, with no work put in at all, their is something just missing. Your aliens would likely engage in dangerous sports like playing Vorzvall on the gas giant Neubon or fighting Ra’Xcars. Anything dangerous really, to give them a sense of feeling uncomfortable and scared. That’s my opinion, change it at will ( :